# Path To Datatbase Does Not Exist | Maven

Tags: sqlite, maven

For a college project we are using Maven to build an app. Our lecturer provided a database and instructions on how to add it to our project. I did a Maven build and it was successful but when I tried to run the attach command you can see that the database I added isn’t there. But it is? If that makes sense. I can see it in Maven, I have opened it to make sure it is there but the code is returning an error. Although you don’t know all the info, would anyone have any suggestions? The dB is using SQLite, I edited the basic app.java file so that it calls the dB https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5NxK.jpg